# Every Matrix a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Every finite-dimensional linear map can be represented by a matrix. But what about the opposite: Does every matrix correspond to a linear map?

Comment: I'm a little confused how you understand finding a matrix for a linear map (which in turn requires you to think of a matrix as a linear map), but not see how a matrix can be thought of as a linear map.  Your question is usually the easy direction of this problem, which is what I find odd.

Comment: The fact that every linear map can be represented by a matrix was infused over and over again as an important fact in my math education. The opposite seems intuitive, but was never specifically touched

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/315258/28900).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, not *every* matrix, necessarily. We could take matrices of arbitrary sets, for example, which needn't have any associated operations.

*However*, assuming that you're taking matrices of elements of some field $\Bbb F,$ then the answer is yes. Given any such matrix, say $A,$ if $A$ is $m\times n,$ then the map $T:\Bbb F^n\to\Bbb F^m$ given by $T(\vec x)=A\vec x$ is linear.

Comment: "A matrix is a rectangular array of numbers or other mathematical objects, for which operations such as addition and multiplication are defined." - Wikipedia. I'm hard pressed to call any rectangular array of elements a matrix.

Comment: That's certainly one definition, and allays the problem nicely. Alternately, one can think of an $m\times n$ matrix as a function on $\{1,...,m\}\times\{1,...,n\}.$ It isn't as nice, to be sure, but it still "looks like a matrix."

Comment: Sure, but I'd disagree that "looks like a matrix" and "is a matrix" is the same thing.

Comment: Feel free! It all depends on if we want to be able to do anything with our matrices, aside from giving a more compact visual form for certain sorts of functions. /shrug/

Comment: Please mention the canonical basis here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If you have a $m\times n$ matrix $M$, then this can be seen as a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ by $M(x) = Mx$.

Answer (score 4):

If $A\in\mathcal M_{n,p}(\Bbb R)$ then the map
$$f\colon \Bbb R^p\rightarrow \Bbb R^n,\quad x\mapsto A x$$
is a linear transformation which's represented by the matrix $A$ in the canonical basis.

Comment: Very well done!